# Can no longer access profile on Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, status-completed, error-message

When I try to visit my profile via Stack Overflow I get redirected [here](https://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/users/4755215/maantje) showing the following **error:** [image: error image]

Going to my profile via https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4755215/maantje seems to work fine.

Comment: No repro.  Is it working for you now?

Comment: @Makoto Nope same error different image.

Comment: I just clicked directly on your profile and am not seeing any errors.  Can you try [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1079354/makoto?tab=profile) to see if it's the same?  What do you see in the error console?

Comment: Your profile works fine, console is empty.

Comment: @Maantje I see the exception that's occuring in our logs. Looking into a fix.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thank you very much for reporting this. Should be fixed now!

Comment: I can confirm it is working again and thank you guys for the insanely short response time!